# setAutoExpandLevel is not working for TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt

I created `TreeViewer` and I put `setAutoExapandLevel` for the tree

```
treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
treeViewer.setContentProvider(new TreeContentProvider());
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new TreeLabelProvider());
treeViewer.setAutoExpandLevel(3);
treeViewer.setInput(new Model());
```

the problem that it is not auto expand for the tree

Do you have any idea why it is not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the model contains all the data when `setInput()` is called?

`internalExpandToLevel(Widget widget, int level)` (where expanding takes place) is called on `inputChanged(Object input, Object oldInput)`. If at the time `setInput` is called the model is empty, no node will be expanded. Even if you later add nodes and call refresh.

To prove this, I changed my snippet from an answer for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520645/checkboxtreeviewer-cant-expand-nodes-by-default/19522952#19522952).

Run this code as it is, then run it with the `empty` field initialized to `true`. You will see the difference.

```
static boolean empty = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    treeViewer.setContentProvider(new DummyContentProvider());
    treeViewer.setAutoExpandLevel(3);
    treeViewer.setInput("root");

    empty = true;
    treeViewer.refresh();

    shell.setSize(200, 200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static class DummyContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        return this.getChildren(inputElement);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
        if (!empty) {
            return new Object[0];
        }
        switch ((String) parentElement) {
            case "root":
                return new String[]{"a", "b"};
            case "a":
                return new String[]{"1"};
            case "b":
                return new Object[]{"1", "2"};
            case "1":
                return new Object[]{"x", "y"};
            default:
                return new String[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParent(Object element) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
        return this.getChildren(element).length > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
    }
}
```